# Having trouble packing blob to proper binary format

Tags: javascript, python, json, serialization

### What I am trying to do

I record mic. I have a chunk of the audio as a `blob` with type `audio/wav`. I want to transfer this data in json and send it over to another machine, which isn't related to a browser. Then that device plays the sound on its system.

### What I have

This is what I am doing on the browser:

```
// .js

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(onMediaSuccess);

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    mediaRecorder.start();
    function handleDataAvailable(blob) {
        BlobUtil.blobToBinaryString(blob).then(function(binaryString) {
                // success
                ws.publish(`com.app.audioStream__`, binaryString);
            }
            console.log('BlobUtil: success')
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // error
            console.log('BlobUtil: error')
        });
    }
}
```

This is my Python side, not much really going on.

```
# .py

import pyaudio

CHUNK = 1024
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
WIDTH = 2

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

stream.start_stream()

# when the .js triggers the event this runs. So on every chunk sent.
def audioStream(data):
    if stream.is_active():
        print data[:100]
        stream.write(data) # encoding error on data

yield self.subscribe(audioStream, 'com.app.audioStream__{}'.format(''))

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
```

The [binaryString](http://pastebin.com/cSEtNtpD) doesn't look correct. It is close to looking like the wav file, but seems like it is using a different encoding.

However, when reading the file (.wav) directly in python it results in the following [byte string](http://pastebin.com/fP7hZtbw).

Also when I transfer my data using sockets which serializes everything in JSON.

So, I need to somehow get from `blob --> binaryString --> json(unicode) --> bytes`. I am unsure if binary string and bytes are somehow different or it is getting ruined by being forced to go through JSON serialization.

---

### Edit:

[toBuffer](https://github.com/feross/blob-to-buffer) is helping.

What I found on another post `JSON cannot encode binary data. You should parse your buffer (probably as UTF8), or use base64.` Going to try it out and see if it works

With the help of toBuffer I was able to get the correct format on the browser side

code:

```
function handleDataAvailable(blob) {
    toBuffer(blob, function(err, buffer) {
        if (err)
            throw err

        ws.publish(`com.app.audioStream__`, buffer.toString());
    });
}
```

However, when I get it from the Python side of the websocket. It displays the data it the correct way, but the encoding is off. Stuck in `unicode` and I can't decode it with anything it always results in a `exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128). However, when I copy and paste the printed data into python terminal and play it from there it works.

It seems when I am getting data from socket which uses JSON may be tampering with the encoding of the binary data.

I also try doing `buffer.toJSON()` which on the receiving end of the JSON I get:

```
[82L, 73L, 70L, 70L, 36L, 192L, 2L, 0L, 87L, 65L, 86L, 69L, 102L, 109L, 116L, 32L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 68L, 172L, 0L
, 0L, 16L, 177L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 100L, 97L, 116L, 97L, 0L, 192L, 2L, 0L, 232L, 255L, 232L, 255L, 254L, 255L, 254L, 255L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 253L, 25
5L, 253L, 255L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 252L, 255L, 252L, 255L, 250L, 255L, 250L, 255L, 243L, 255L, 243L, 255L, 251L, 255L, 251L, 255L, 249L, 255L
, 249L, 255L, 250L, 255L, 250L, 255L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 7L, 0L]
```

I am unsure what to do with this info. I am guessing it is long representation of bytes. So bytes array, which I need to convert to a bytes string.

I found this on another post:

```
def Dump(n): 
  s = '%x' % n
  if len(s) & 1:
    s = '0' + s
  return s.decode('hex')
print repr(Dump(1245427))  #: '\x13\x00\xf3'
```

Trying to pull apart the binary data above.

`b''.join([Dump(i) for i in data])`

I yield

```
'RIFF$\xc0\x02\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00D\xac\x00\x00\x10\xb1\x02\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00data\x00\xc0\x02\x00\xe8\xff\xe8\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\x05\x00\x05\x00\xfd\x19\x05\xfd\xff\x03\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfc\xff\xfc\xff\xfa\xff\xfa\xff\xf3\xff\xf3\xff\xfb\xff\xfb\xff\xf9\xff\xf9\xff\xfa\xff\xfa\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\x07\x00\x07\x00'
```

It is close, but I need it to be something more like `RIFFX�WAVEfmt D��Xdata4�`

I cannot really do anything with it. Some of the bytes in there just won't allow for any en/de-coding. I just don't know where to go to get the proper format.

I may not be understanding how my information is being handling when going through the socket and being read.

Comment: I think it should work if you send an array buffer: https://medium.com/@dulitharw/recording-audio-on-the-browser-c8f262cbb4d2#.h5el4l4y4

Comment: If I am reading this right (it is long) you think the problem is in the python code, but you don't show that code.  Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: @StephenRauch I added Python code, although there isn't much going on. I believe it has to do with how JSON is serializing the data, but missing some bytes. Trying to figure a way to convert the bytes into something JSON will not tamper with.

Comment: If you are not certain whether or not the data is getting munged by sender or receiver, I suggest using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), and looking at the packet `on the wire`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to find the issue and resolve it.

Main issue was the software I was using to interface using websockets.
It's serialization method defaulted to JSON, however, JSON has been modifying my byte data.

I had the websocket framework use a different serializer, `msgpack`, which can handle bytes properly and not corrupt the data.